# Lua C API: Delete metatable created with luaL_newmetatable?

Tags: lua, lua-api

How can I delete a metatable `foo` created with `luaL_newmetatable( L, "foo" );`, so that `luaL_getmetatable( L, "foo" );` will push a NIL value again?

Answer (score 4):

Whatever the reason you may have to delete the metatable, it is possible. `luaL_newmetatable(L, "foo")` creates a table, which is stored in the Lua registry with the key `"foo"`.

To delete the table, just set the field `"foo"` in the registry to `nil`. The code in C:

```
lua_pushnil(L);
lua_setfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "foo");
```

Equivalent code in Lua:

```
debug.getregistry()["foo"] = nil
```